# Access a route without .htaccess in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, cron, frameworks

There's any way to access a route without using the mod_rewrite apache module?
For example if I've my route as **example.com/products** I'd access into that as **example.com/index.php?path=products** or something like that I've spent a lot of time researching with no success.

Any idea?